# What are the shields on the ribbons for?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

On the stats screen in the tavern of dungeon defenders I see a ribbon for each of the difficulties I have passed for a level/map.  Some of them have a shield in the middle and some do not.  What does the shield signify?
[image: Immage]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shield indicates that you've cleared that difficulty (or a harder difficulty) in [Hardcore Mode](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Hardcore_Mode).

Comment: Thanks!  I confirmed by playing one of the non-shield level/maps on hardcore and got the shield afterward.  However, the shield appears to be awarded on a level/map basis not on a difficulty basis.  I played hardcore on hard and the shield appeared for all ribbons.

Comment: @SeanB, I think it will give you credit for completion on the hardest difficulty + any lower ones.  Did you get the Insane shield for playing on Hard?

Comment: Yep that's it.  I played a level on insane that I hadn't previously completed, but not on hardcore and the shield was not on the insane ribbon, but was on the hard and lower ribbons (since I had hardcored on hard).

Comment: @SeanB, okay, cool.  I thought that was the way it worked.  I made a small edit so that my answer reflects this clarification.